# HDF5, Reference in C++

Tags: c++, hdf5

Does somebody know how to make a HDF5 dataset reference with the c++ API.

I have the following function which so far works, but is it the right way for using only the C++ API?

```
template<typename TFileGroup>
void saveReferences(const TFileGroup & fg , std::vector<hobj_ref_t> & refs, std::string name = "StateRefs"){

    H5::DataSpace ds( 1, refs.size());
    H5::DataSet refset = fg->createDataSet(name, H5::PredType::STD_REF_OBJ, ds);
    refset.write(&refs[0], PredType::STD_REF_OBJ);
}
```

Which takes a vector of references previously constructed by the `H5::Location::reference(...)` function (base class of group or data set classes) and saves them in a data set `name` under the group `fg`

Is there a `hobj_ref_t` object in C++ as well or is it simply the same?...

Comment: Please included the relevant code in your question, not as a link. Obviously, it isn't feasible to include the full listing, so cut it down to only what's necessary to illustrate your question.

Comment: did that :-)! thanks for the comment